# Microsoft Exchange CDOEX in a clustered environment

Tags: c++, exchange-server

We have a VS2005 native C++ application which connects to Exchange
server using CDOEX and CDOEXM to create and modify calendar entries
for multiple user folders. It's a command line utility which must be installed on the same server where the exchange server is installed. What is the correct procedure to use this
utility in a clustered environment? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Might I suggest you take a look at.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373130%28VS.85%29.aspx
for general information on how failover clustering works.
But I would also like to point out that going forward ( ie exchange 2007 , 2010) you don't get CDOEXM.  And Instead you will have to find some way of integrating with powershell instead.  There are classes to explicitly run powershell scripting from inside a program, but they are C# so you either migrate all your code to C# or use some bastardized blend of IJW.